# Improving speed from zip to json

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some financial data organised as zip files. One zip file for each trading day since 2007. Each file contains between 150'000 to 550'000 records/rows and 20 columns/features or so. I need to re-organize the data following the using logic:
/DataFolder/{Year}/{Column1}/{Column2}/{filename}.json

For clarity Column1 is the Ticker column and Column2 is the ExpiryDate column.
Additionally for each ticker-expiryDate pair in a single file I want to populate a new column (of 0 or 1) which is the at-the money strike (given the value in column StockPrice, I get the closest value of the strike column to the stock price).

I then write the data (for each ticker-expiryDate pair) as a json file on my hard drive.

Initially I was going for some "brute-force" approach ie load the zip file as a dataframe and did some sorting on tickers and expiry dates. Obviously this was not optimal. It took about 12minutes to process a single zip file.

I then tried to improve my code by using the groups generated with pandas groupby function. It did improve the performance to slightly below 10 minutes per zip file. But still given I have close to 3'000 files to process I need to improve things massively...

I use a function to get the nearest strike given the stock price:

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]
```

I use the following code for each zip file:

```
def process_directory(files2proc):
    #files2proc list of files to process

    for filename in files2proc:    
        df_zip = pd.read_csv(filename)
        df_grouped = df_zip.groupby(['ticker', 'expirDate'])

        for name, group in df_grouped:
            expYear = str(name[1])[-4:]
            exp_fmt = str(pd.to_datetime(name[1]).date()).replace('-', '')


            temp_path = '/Volumes/DataFolder/{}/{}/{}/{}/'.format(name[0][0], name[0], expYear, exp_fmt)
            dir_path = pathlib.Path(temp_path)
            dir_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

            df_temp = df_grouped.get_group(name).reset_index(drop=True)

            strikes = df_temp['strike'].unique()
            stkprice = df_temp['stkPx'].iloc[0]
            atm_strike = find_nearest(strikes, stkprice)

            df_temp['atTheMoney'] = df_temp['strike'] == atm_strike

            file_path = temp_path + '_' + name[0] + '_' + exp_fmt + '.json'

            if not os.path.exists(file_path):
                df_temp.to_json(file_path, orient="records")
            else:
                df_orig = pd.read_json(file_path, orient="records")
                df_calls_up = df_orig.append(df_temp)
                df_calls_up.to_json(file_path, orient="records")
```

I fear the .reset_index and .iloc statements are time-consumming. How can I by-pass the call to find_nearest in order to improve speed? If not, is there a vectorized way of populating the at-the-money column?
More generally I think I create too many temporary dataframes which are not helping the overall speed (?)

Edit: the zip contains only one csv file. I have reproduced part of a csv example below:

```
ticker stkPx expirDate  strike (other columns) trade_date
AAPL   34.3  1/20/2007  32.5                   1/3/2007 
AAPL   34.3  1/20/2007  35                     1/3/2007
AAPL   34.3  1/20/2007  37.5                   1/3/2007
AAPL   34.3  2/17/2007  30                     1/3/2007
AAPL   34.3  2/17/2007  35                     1/3/2007
AAPL   34.3  2/17/2007  40                     1/3/2007
(...)
```

I need to re-organize this file into several json files as follow:
Datafolder/A/AAPL/2007/20070120/_AAPL_20070120.json
Datafolder/A/AAPL/2007/20070120/_AAPL_20070217.json

using this format:
Datafolder/{TickerInitial}/{Ticker}/{year of expirDate}/{expirDate as yyyymmdd}/*{ticker}*{expirDate as yyyymmdd}.json

Each json file should have an extra column (on top of the columns from the original  zip file) called atTheMoney to flag the at the money options ie for _AAPL_20070120.json:

```
ticker stkPx expirDate  strike (other columns) trade_date atTheMoney
AAPL   34.3  1/20/2007  32.5                   1/3/2007   False
AAPL   34.3  1/20/2007  35                     1/3/2007   True
AAPL   34.3  1/20/2007  37.5                   1/3/2007   False
```

and for _AAPL_20070217.json:

```
ticker stkPx expirDate  strike (other columns) trade_date  atTheMoney
AAPL   34.3  2/17/2007  30                     1/3/2007    False
AAPL   34.3  2/17/2007  35                     1/3/2007    True
AAPL   34.3  2/17/2007  40                     1/3/2007    False
```

The at the money flag correspond to the closest strike column value given the stkPx column value( ie the strike 35 is the closest value of 34.3 to [32.5, 35, 37.5] or [30, 35, 40])

Edit2: here is my amended version of JonSG:

```
def process_file(zip_path, ifilename):

    stage_1 = collections.defaultdict(list)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path) as zf:
        with zf.open(ifilename + ".csv", "r") as file_in:
            reader = csv.reader(TextIOWrapper(file_in, 'utf-8'))
            colnames = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(next(reader))}
            for row in reader:
                key = f"{row[colnames['ticker']]}_{row[colnames['expirDate']]}"
                stage_1[key].append(row)

    for key, value in stage_1.items():
        min_strike_delta = float("inf")
        for row in value:
            row.append(abs(float(row[colnames['stkPx']]) - float(row[colnames['strike']])))
            if min_strike_delta > row[-1]:
                min_strike_delta = row[-1]

    value = [
        {
            **{cname: row[cvalue] for cname, cvalue in colnames.items()},
            **{"atTheMoney": row[-1] == min_strike_delta}
        }
        for row in value
    ]

    ticker, expirDate = key.split("_")
    exp_fmt = str(pd.to_datetime(expirDate).date()).replace('-', '')
    temp_path = f"/Volumes/DataCenter/{ticker[0]}/{ticker}/{exp_fmt[:4]}/{exp_fmt}/"
    filename = f"{temp_path}_{ticker}_{exp_fmt}.json"
    dir_path = pathlib.Path(temp_path)
    dir_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    with open(filename, "a+") as file_out:
        for row in value:
            file_out.write(json.dumps(row) + ",\n")
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see an example of your actual input data and the result you seek. Is a solution via pandas required?

Comment: I added an example of the data in edit to the OP. A solution via pandas is not required (I just used it because I thought I would be more comfortable with)

Comment: Are all the records with the same "key" contiguous? If so, there is an additional set of changes that will make this even faster!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "contiguous": I didn't sort the data and the data comes from a data vendor so I wouldn't rely too much on them (one day they could switch their methodology ...). To be honest this is already crazy fast compared to my initial tests.

Comment: If in a file all the `AAPL 1/20/2007` rows are already one after the other all together then all the `AAPL 2/17/2007` rows and so on, then we can make a change that will make this even faster

Comment: I can't guarantee that with the raw data; it would require some sorting prior.

For reading back the data I took off the "," and used "/n" then I can load the json records file using json_normalize and produce a dataframe

Comment: I have reached to the data vendor to confirm it. In the meantime I tried to run it:
at first it took about 15 seconds to process each file but after 100 files, it was taking over 10 minutes to process a file. I tried to clean the Cached Files because I thought maybe my computer /pycharm was caching these zip/csv file somehow but that didn't help. Although the number of records/rows per file does increase (in 2007 it starts at 100K and peaks at 130K), I would guess the processing time to be slightly higher (like maybe 25seconds instead of 15seconds) be not 10 minutes

Comment: The solution from JonSG works nicely. I did a few test and found out that the performance issue is due to my hardawre/setup: using an external hard drive/internet via a dock is too much to handle for the dock. Using the internal hard drive (or pluging an external hard drive directly to the computer) fixed the performance issue. Thanks JonSG!

Comment: I managed to process data from 2007 to 2014. But now each file takes about 40 seconds to process because the number of rows is getting larger. I got confirmation from the vendor that the data is always sorted by ticker then expiry then strikes (ie as you wrote: in a file all the AAPL 1/20/2007 rows are already one after the other all together then all the AAPL 2/17/2007 rows and so on); I would be very interested in your way of making it even faster @JonSG

Comment: Sure thing. I'll add a second "answer", though I fear at this point the slowdown *might* be related to opening and seeking to the end of many files to append to them. In any case, I'll do an update taking that new info into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know that the data is clustered by the key, we can leverage this fact to reduce the amount of work we need to do. We only need to read through the data once now.

```
import csv
import json

## ---------------------
## Funtion to handle writing data.
## this way we don't repeate ourselves
## ---------------------
def append_data(key, rows, min_strike_delta, colnames):
    if not rows:
        return

    ticker, expirDate = key.split("_")
    filename = f"{ticker[0]}_{ticker}_{expirDate.replace('/', '')}.json"
    with open(filename, "a+") as file_out:
        for row in rows:
            row[-1] = row[-1] == min_strike_delta
            row_json = {cname: row[cvalue] for cname, cvalue in colnames.items()}
            file_out.write(json.dumps(row_json) + "\n")
## ---------------------

## ---------------------
## Let's use the fact that rows are already grouped by key to our advantage:
## ---------------------
with open("strike.csv", "r") as file_in:
    reader = csv.reader(file_in)
    colnames = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(next(reader) + ["atTheMoney"])}

    current_key = ""
    current_rows = []
    current_min_strike_delta = float("inf")

    for row in reader:
        key = f"{row[colnames['ticker']]}_{row[colnames['expirDate']]}"

        ## ---------------------
        ## If the keys are different try to write out the prior batch of rows
        ## ---------------------
        if key != current_key:
            append_data(current_key, current_rows, current_min_strike_delta, colnames)
            current_key = key
            current_rows = []
            current_min_strike_delta = float("inf")
        ## ---------------------

        strike_delta = abs(float(row[colnames['stkPx']]) - float(row[colnames['strike']]))
        current_min_strike_delta = min(current_min_strike_delta, strike_delta)
        row.append(strike_delta)
        current_rows.append(row)

## ---------------------
## If there are any remaining rows write them out
## ---------------------
append_data(current_key, current_rows, current_min_strike_delta, colnames)
## ---------------------
```

When run it should give us two files:

**A_AAPL_1202007.json:**

```
{"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "1/20/2007", "strike": "32.5", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": false}
{"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "1/20/2007", "strike": "35", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": true}
{"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "1/20/2007", "strike": "37.5", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": false}
```

**A_AAPL_2172007.json:**

```
{"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "2/17/2007", "strike": "30", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": false}
{"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "2/17/2007", "strike": "35", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": true}
{"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "2/17/2007", "strike": "40", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": false}
```

At this point, the slowdown might be due to repeatedly opening files and seeking to the end of them to append.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might look at doing this in a more manual way.

Start with our modules:

```py
import collections
import csv
import json
```

Then we can:

```py
## ---------------------
## Gather the rows of data by key
## ---------------------
stage_1 = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open("strike.csv", "r") as file_in:
    reader = csv.reader(file_in)
    colnames = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(next(reader))}
    for row in reader:
        key = f"{row[colnames['ticker']]}_{row[colnames['expirDate']]}"
        stage_1[key].append(row)
## ---------------------
```

Now we have a dictionary with a key of your grouping id and values of the individual rows for the given key.

Now for each key in the above dictionary we will determine the `atTheMoney` status of all of the rows for that key, then write out a csv.

```
## ---------------------
## For each key find the minimum strike delta and update the values
## based on it. then write to output file
## ---------------------
for key, value in stage_1.items():
    ## --------------------
    ## find the min_strike_delta 
    ## --------------------
    min_strike_delta = float("inf")
    for row in value:
        row.append(abs(float(row[colnames['stkPx']]) - float(row[colnames['strike']])))
        if min_strike_delta > row[-1]:
            min_strike_delta = row[-1]
    ## --------------------

    ## --------------------
    ## Cast value to a list of dictionaries rather than a list of lists.
    ## This is a little heavier so let's just do it part by part rather than as part of stage 1
    ## --------------------
    value = [
        {
            **{cname: row[cvalue] for cname, cvalue in colnames.items()},
            **{"atTheMoney": row[-1] == min_strike_delta}
        }
        for row in value
    ]
    ## --------------------

    ## --------------------
    ## Create a result file name.
    ## This is just a simple one for testing and yours is more complicated
    ## --------------------
    ticker, expirDate = key.split("_")
    filename = f"{ticker[0]}_{ticker}_{expirDate.replace('/', '')}.json"
    ## --------------------

    ## --------------------
    ## Overwrite the list to output file.
    ## --------------------
    #with open(filename, "w", newline="") as file_out:
    #    json.dump(value, file_out)
    ## --------------------

    ## --------------------
    ## To append rows to a prior file
    ## You probably don't want an actual json array
    ## you probably want rows of json records...
    ## --------------------
    with open(filename, "a+") as file_out:
        for row in value:
            file_out.write(json.dumps(row) + ",\n")
    ## --------------------
## ---------------------
```

with your test data, this produces a couple of files:

**A_AAPL_1202007.json**:

```
[
    {"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "1/20/2007", "strike": "32.5", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": false},
    {"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "1/20/2007", "strike": "35", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": true},
    {"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "1/20/2007", "strike": "37.5", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": false}
]
```

**A_AAPL_2172007.json**

```
[
    {"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "2/17/2007", "strike": "30", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": false},
    {"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "2/17/2007", "strike": "35", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": true},
    {"ticker": "AAPL", "stkPx": "34.3", "expirDate": "2/17/2007", "strike": "40", "trade_date": "1/3/2007", "atTheMoney": false}
]
```

Hopefully this is faster than what you have now.

Comment: Thanks a lot JonSG, that's definitively going on the right direction. However this produces a set of csv files. Is there something equivalent to csv.writer with json? 

When processing another zip file corresponding for another trade_date, I will have another pair of AAPL with that specific expiry. Using the code should append the "new" data to the previously created/updated file right?

Comment: same output (so with all the columns plus the atTheMoney) with orient='records'

So doing this, it allows me to by pass the test as to whether the file already exist?

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to produce json results :-)

Comment: This code creates a new set of files by key each run, if you want to append rows run to run that gets a little trickier. You might use an `open()` mode of `"a+"` to append, but in that case you probably don't want to write rows as a proper json array, but as lines of json rows. Some AWS services return larger json payloads like this so that the data can be streamed row by row rather than having a lexically complete array. If you want that let me know and I can update the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to support appending rows of json to a file. I believe this format is called "json records"

Comment: Wow this looks fantastic. One little thing though: is it possible to keep the type float for "stkPx", "strike" instead of having them as string?

Comment: I added a "with" statement to open the zip file into a csv filename prior to your "with" statement. I gave it a go and this is lightening fast! However now I lost the [] characters at the begining/end of the .json file. I also have a "," after the last entry. Both (missing [], extra ",") create an issue when loading the file into a dataframe later on

Comment: Yes, the "[" and "]" are intentionally not there as the file is now individual rows of json records not a json array. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming. This allows for efficient appending of new rows.

Comment: Yes this is really an improvement in terms of speed. For accessing/doing data analysis on these files this will be most likely done with pandas. I had a look at pandas.read_json but didn't see anthing which would allow me to load these rows of dictionnaries (?) I can always create a "get" function which would open the file, add "[" at the beginning, and replace the final "," by "]" but it might be easier to do it here or having a pandas read function that takes these processed files as input and return a dataframe (?)